# Saniting and Escaping HTML, Javascript and CSS Code

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a custom WordPress plugin that gets JS and CSS code from the user.

I would like to know how I can sanitize and escape the input correctly. The user inputs some JS and CSS code and it will be encoded via Javascript and sent to the database via Ajax.

I tried to use base64 encode in JS and saved it to the database.

On the php side, I used

```
base64_decode( strip_tags( $str ) );
```

which seems to be working, but I don't want to use base64, and I'm not sure if this would be enough for security.

Is there an alternative way to encode and decode HTML, JS and CSS codes including sanitizing and escaping correctly?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What security problems are you trying to protect against? It's practically impossible to allow users to input JavaScript and not be vulnerable to all manor of XSS attacks.

Comment: I know that it's impossible, but I would like be secure as much as possible.

Comment: I decided to use base64. I couldn't find a better way and ended up implementing the base64_decode and encode functionality.